# If $(X,d')$ is totally bounded and $d'$ and $d$ are topologically equivalent then $(X, d)$ is separable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to write something similar to the proof of

> If $(X,d)$ totally bounded then $(X,d)$ separable

but I dont know how to use topological equivalence here. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

So you've got that $(X,d')$ is separable. So there exists a countable dense subset $A\subset X$ (this in fact means (according to the definition of a topology generated by metrics) that each $\varepsilon$-ball with respect to $d'$ contains a point from $A$). Take this subset and show that it's going to be dense if you consider balls with respect to $d$ instead of $d'$. It's easy - if your distances generate the same topology, it means that any ball with respect to $d$ contains some ball with respect to $d'$ which in its turn contains a point from $A$.

Comment: In case you need the proof of the fact that if $(X,d')$ is totally bounded it is separable, here it is. For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ fix a finite $\frac1{n}$-net $F_n$. Then clearly  $F= \cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} F_n$ is countable. So this set $F$ is dense in $(X,d')$. To see why this is so, consider arbitrary $x\in X$ and $\varepsilon$-ball around it. We can choose $n$ such that $\frac1{n} <\varepsilon$. Then, since $F_n$ is an $\frac1{n}$-net, there is $y\in F_n$ such that $\frac1{n}$-ball around $y$ contains $x$. But this means that $y$ is contained in our $\varepsilon$-ball around $x$!

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use the topological definition of density instead of the metric one, the proof is quite simple: let $S$ be a dense subset of $(X,d')$ (which must exist, since $(X,d')$ was totally bounded, and hence separable).  Since $(X,d')$ and $(X,d)$ were assumed to be topologically equivalent, they have the same topology, so the identity function $i: (X,d') \to (X,d)$ is a homeomorphism.  It follows that $i(S) = S$ is dense in $(X,d)$, and since we already assumed that $S$ was countable, we are done.

Comment: How do you know that if d and d` are top equivalent they have the same dense sets?

Comment: In topology, a dense set is defined in terms of open sets ($S$ is dense in $X$ whenever for every $x \in X$, either $x \in S$ or every open set containing $x$ contains a point of $S$.)  Topological equivalence tells me that $(X,d)$ and $(X,d')$ have the same open sets, so they must also have the same dense sets.  

If you're asking specifically about how I concluded that $i(S) = S$ was dense in $(X,d)$, this is a property of homeomorphisms: they preserve denseness.